# how can I use bluebird's promisify with a function that has no parameter?

Tags: javascript, bluebird

is this even possible or good practice?
I have a function that just returns a value from a database, a config parameter, it doesnt need any parameter. But if I promisify a function that only has one argument callback, the passed parameter from a previous promise in a then chain is passed onto the callback variable instead.

does someone have an idea? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you promisify it manually then?

Comment: I think you're the function you're looking for is Promise.method().